# Accessing django models and functions from within python script hosted on separate heroku app

Tags: python, django, heroku

I'm looking for a way to access the models and functions in my django app hosted on heroku from a python script on a different heroku app.

I understand that the following works if the script that you have is located in the same folder as your django app:

```
import os 
import django 
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "app.settings")
django.setup()
from manual_tasks.tasks import *
```

but I'm looking to run the script on a different heroku app entirely. Is this possible? In this case, I wouldn't have the path/to/django-app because my script would be hosted on a separate heroku app.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If the files from your `django-app` aren't available on the same VM/container as the script, then you can’t.  You can only access your django app, well, if you have access to the files that make up your django app.

Comment: ok, that makes sense. thanks!