# how to perform database operations on single database using django and falcon

Tags: mysql, django, sqlalchemy, django-orm, falconframework

I am thinking of creating a project for which I chose 2 python frameworks, django and falcon. I will be using Falcon to build APIs and Django for other operations.I don't understand, how to manage database operations in both the frameworks which will be accessing single database(mysql database).

My plan is to create tables using Django models into the database, but how about accessing the database values in falcon. I am not much aware about sqlalchemy. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the motivation in using both Django and Falcon? It would seem that with things like the Django REST Framework http://www.django-rest-framework.org/ you'd be able to build everything together.

Comment: falcon will help me in saving few microseconds while serving each request. I liked django's admin module. Thinking of using the django's admin module only. The APIs through which end users will interact with system will be built using falcon.

Answer (score 2):

If you're dead-set on trying to access Django models from Falcon then this does look possible.

Apparently as long as your Django app's code is present wherever your Falcon app is, it looks like that you could use it as described in [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41731330/accessing-django-models-and-functions-from-within-python-script-hosted-on-separa):

```
import os 
import django 
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "app.settings")
django.setup()
from yourdjangoapp.things import *
```

Comment: thanks for the solution, just one more question, can I access same database using SQL Alchemy and Django ORM easily?